# Django -- Generate form based on queryset

Tags: python, django, forms

I've got a question which I'll ask two ways: short & generic, so future generations of StackOverflow readers will benefit, and Long & Detailed, so I can get my work done without screwing anything up.

## Short & Generic Version:

How do I make Django generate a table-like form where some info in the table is from the database, and the user fills in the rest? On form submission, each row in the table should become a record in the database (after it's validated, of course).

What's the cleanest way to do this? What's this mode of interaction cannonically called?

**Example Form**

```
|=============================================================|
| QueriedValue | CalculatedValue | User_data | More_User_data |
|_____________________________________________________________|
|     Foo 1    |    Bar 1        |           |                |
|     Foo 2    |    Bar 2        |           |                |
|     Foo 3    |    Bar 3        |           |                |
...            ...               ...         ...              |
|     Foo n    |    Bar n        |           |                |
|=============================================================|

    ++++++++++
    | Submit |
    ++++++++++
```

**Resulting Database Records**

```
     TimeStamp + fk_Foo = natural primary key for this table
    ________________
   /                \
|===========================================================|
|   TimeStamp  |    fk_Foo    | User_data | More_User_data  |
|___________________________________________________________|
| submit_time  |     Foo 1    |  Datum 1  | AnotherDatum 1  |
| submit_time  |     Foo 2    |  Datum 2  | AnotherDatum 2  |
| submit_time  |     Foo 3    |  Datum 3  | AnotherDatum 3  |
|...           ...            ...              ...          |
| submit_time  |     Foo n    |  Datum n  | AnotherDatum n  |
|===========================================================|
```

## Long Version

I'm writing a web app to track gas cylinder usage at my company. We have a bunch of gas plumbing in our building, and we need to know which gas cylinder was hooked up to which gas line at what time.

I'd like two forms for the technicians to fill out:

1. **Daily Inventory**: Every morning, the stockroom guy needs to look at each gas line and record the line's pressure, and the reference number of the bottle. This generates bunch of 4-tuple records (time, line, bottle, psi); one for each line, every morning.
2. **As-Needed Bottle Change**: After doing the daily inventory, if a bottle is almost out it needs to be changed, and that change needs to be logged. This should add another entry to the table of bottles for the new bottle, and another 4-tuple with the new (time, line, bottle, psi) info for the new connection. This happens to a random line a few times a week, but not every day.

So to keep track of this I'm writing a Django application. I've got the following models:

```
# models.py
class GasFarm(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a gas farm -- a collection of lines that are grouped together and managed as a unit.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Bottle(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a gas bottle -- the physical cylinder -- that contains a mixture of gases.
    """

    # Options
    get_latest_by = 'date_added'

    # Fields
    BACKGROUND_TYPES = (
        ('h2/n2', "H2/N2"),
        ('h2/air', "H2/Air"),
        ('h2', "H2"),
        ('n2', "N2"),
        ('other', "Other"),
    )


    ppm = models.FloatField()
    mix = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=BACKGROUND_TYPES, default='n2')
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)  # Every bottle has a unique ref or somebody fucked up.
    cert_date = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    def pct(self):
        return float(self.ppm)/10**4


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} ({}% {})".format(self.ref, self.pct(), self.mix,)


class Line(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a gas line -- the physical plumbing -- that delivers gas from the bottles to the test stations.

    It is assumed that a gas line can have zero or one gas bottles attached to it at any given time. The Line model
    maps bottle objects and time-sensitive Reading objects to test stations.
    """

    # Fields
    gasfarm = models.ForeignKey(GasFarm)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    bottles = models.ManyToManyField(Bottle, through='Reading')

    # Calculated fields. "current" is definitely not optional -- that's a super common query. The others? I'm not so
    # sure...
    def current(self):
        """
        Returns the most recently recorded Reading object associated with the line
        """
        return self.reading_set.latest(field_name='time')
    current.short_description = "latest reading"


    def last_checked(self):
        """
        Returns the date & time at which the most recent Reading object associated with this line was logged
        """
        return self.current().time
    last_checked.short_description = "last updated"

    def has_recent_reading(self):
        """
        Boolean flag for whether the reading is probably valid, or if someone needs to go out and take a new one.
        """
        latest_reading = self.current().time
        return timezone.now() - latest_reading < datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    has_recent_reading.boolean = True
    has_recent_reading.short_description = "Is data current?"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.number


class Reading(models.Model):
    """
    A Reading links a Bottle to a Line at a given time, and provides a snapshot of the pressure at that time.
    """

    # Options
    get_latest_by = 'time'

    # Fields
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    bottle = models.ForeignKey(Bottle)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    psi = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(2500)])

    def ref(self):
        """
        The reference number of the bottle listed in the reading
        """
        return self.bottle.ref
    def ppm(self):
        """
        The PPM concentration of the bottle listed in the reading
        """
        return self.bottle.ppm

    def pct(self):
        """
        The % concentration of the bottle listed in the reading
        """
        return self.bottle.pct()

    def mix(self):
        """
        The gas mix (e.g. H2/N2) of the associated bottle
        """
        return self.bottle.mix

    def __unicode__(self):
        # Example:
        # A0: 327.3 PPM H2/N2 2300 psi
        return "{}, {}: {} PPM {} {} psi".format(self.line, self.time, self.ppm(), self.mix(), self.psi)
```

I've populated the database with our back-log of data using some scripts, and I've written a few views to pull data *out* of the databse; I'm happy with them so far, and the results look very promising -- at least for displaying stored data.

But I'm not sure how to cleanly populate the database using HTML forms. I'd like the forms to be basically two separate "worksheets" -- like the kind the DMV gives you, with nice clear instructions #justkidding.

### Form 1: Daily Inventory

The form would list all the lines in a given farm, display what bottle should be on each line (based on previous readings/updates), and then prompt the user to enter a value. This would require that the technician update the pressure of every bottle on every line each time they submit the form -- we want a global snapshot of the whole gas system. In a perfect world, the form would pre-fill the current time and each line's most recent pressure reading into the Reading Time and Pressure fields to ease data entry.

```
# Cells with brackets [] are system-supplied, non-editable data displayed in the table. 
# Cells without brackets are pre-filled with sensible defaults, but are user editable.
|  [Line]  | [Current Bottle]  |  Reading Time   |   Pressure (psi)   |
===============================================================
|   [A0]   |   [15-1478334]    |  2014-7-14 9:34 |       2400         |
|   [A1]   |   [15-1458661]    |  2014-7-14 9:34 |        500         |
|   [A2]   |   [15-4851148]    |  2014-7-14 9:34 |       1850         |
|   [A3]   |   [15-1365195]    |  2014-7-14 9:34 |        700         |
...
...
|   [C18]  |   [15-9555813]    |  2014-7-14 9:34 |        2350        |
|=====================================================================|
```

After reading through the Django docs on Forms, ModelForms, and Formsets, I've written some code that does **almost** everything I want -- but the Line and Bottle information are editable form fields, and I need them to be static guideposts for filling in the rest of the form. They *do* need to be present in the generated database records, though.

I am dimly aware of the readonly and disabled attributes, and of what appear to be kludgy solutions to clean data from the POST variable in the response when you want to have read-only stuff in forms, but I'm still not clear on how those work or why they're necessary. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to get what I"m after? Perhaps forms with programmatically generated headings, or annotations? That's all I really want: an auto-generated guide to filling out the form.

```
# Forms.py
 class PressureReadingUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Reading

PsiReadingFormset = formset_factory(PressureReadingUpdate, extra=0)

# views.py
def update_pressure(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = forms.PsiReadingFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            cd = formset.cleaned_data
            # do something? I'm not here yet...
    else:
        lines = models.Line.objects.all()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        initial = [{'line': l,
                    'psi': l.current().psi,
                    "bottle": l.current().bottle,
                    'time': now} for l in lines]

        formset = forms.PsiReadingFormset(initial=initial,)
    return render(request, 'gas_tracking/gasfarm_form_psi_reading.html', {'formset': formset})
```

### Form 2: Change a Gas Bottle

I'd like a list of all the gas lines, with the current bottle & pressure (easy-- this is done elsewhere), and then a button that makes a pop-up window where you can submit a new bottle, much like you find in the admin interface. How do I make pop-up windows? How do I make buttons? I'm not even sure where to start with this one yet

I'm still very new to Django, and I've searched high and low, but haven't found anything that answers my question -- maybe I'm just not using the right keywords?

Thanks for your help.

-Matt

Comment: Some suggestions:
For Form 1, why don't you render the static data using a queryset and populate an empty formset with initial data from the queryset. This prevents the need to have to deal with disabling form elements.

As for Form 2, you probably have to look at jquery/ajax to achieve that in the front-end.

Comment: I wound up storing the data on the form itself using the answer I posted below. That way I could render the static data from the form instance, and also customize the <input> tag labels and request.POST dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Dynamically generating Forms using FormSets

So I figured this out (after much googling and swearing and gnashing of teeth).  Malcolm Tredinnick made a blog post about exactly what I wanted to do, which a kind soul preserved on [Django Snippets](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1955/)

Using Malcom's code as a model, I solved my problem and **it works like a charm**

```
class PressureReadingUpdate(forms.Form):
    """
    Form that asks for the pressure of a line given some attributes of that line.
    """
    psi = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.line = kwargs.pop('line')
        kwargs['auto_id'] = "%s".format(self.line.number)
        super(PressureReadingUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BasePsiReadingFormset(BaseFormSet):
    """
    Formset that constructs a group of PressureReadingUpdate forms by taking a queryset
    of Line objects and passing each one in turn to a PressureReadingUpdate form as it
    gets constructed
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lines = kwargs.pop('lines')
        super(BasePsiReadingFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.extra = len(self.lines)
        self.max_num = len(self.lines)

    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        kwargs['line'] = self.lines[i]
        form = super(BasePsiReadingFormset, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
        return form

PsiReadingFormset = formset_factory(form=PressureReadingUpdate, formset=BasePsiReadingFormset)
```

This gives you a Formset with an extra kwarg you can pass down the chain of constructors. You can use it in a view (along with a more typical `initial=` kwarg) with:

```
formset = PsiReadingFormset(lines=lines,
                            initial=[{'psi': l.current().psi} for l in lines],
```

So here's the best explanation I can think of:

Any kwargs passed to a FormSet like (which gets made by the `formset_factory` function using a non-default 'BaseFormSet' as a blueprint) get passed along -- mostly unaltered -- to  the `__init__` method of whatever `BaseFormSet` the `FormSet` is based on.

This means you can define custom behavior in `BaseFormSet.__init__`, and you can relay runtime data to the `BaseFormSet.__init__` method by passing it as a keyword argument to `FormSet` (that's the `lines=` kwarg in my example above). I use it to set an attribute on on `formset` (an instance of a `FormSet` based on 'BasePsiReadingFormset').

Confused yet? I was too at first.

**But the real magic** is understanding how `_construct_forms` works: A `FormSet` calls this function each time it wants to make a new `Form` in the set. It will relay any unrecognized kwargs to to the constructor of the `Form` it is supposed to manage a set of.

So you just need to overload your custom `BaseFormSet`'s `._construct_forms` to wrap the original `_construct_forms` of the superclass and inject a new kwarg. This kwarg will then be passed through to the constructor of your custom Form class, and shape the new `Form` instance according to the `Form`'s initialization function.

And that, ladies and gentlemen, is how you can have a FormSet that has a bunch of similarly-defined but dynamically-generated-and-slightly different forms in it.

After understanding this, I can see the elegance of it. However, it uses some intermediate-to-advanced python, and is neither immediately obvious nor well documented. If you are struggling with this like I did, feel free to message me.